# Is every Hilbert space the completion of some incomplete pre-Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, complete-spaces

Is every Hilbert space the completion of some incomplete pre-Hilbert space?  It is certainly true of the classical Hilbert space.  But for a general Hilbert space, I would imagine that one uses some generalized notion of bases, of which I know nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every finite-dimensional normed vector space is complete, so a finite-dimensional Hilbert space cannot be the completion of an incomplete pre-Hilbert space.  But every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space is the competion of an incomplete pre-Hilbert space.  Indeed, it is the completion of any dense subspace, so you just have a to find a dense proper subspace.  You can do this, for instance, by taking an orthonormal basis $B$ for the Hilbert space and taking the subspace of all finite linear combinations of elements of $B$.

Comment: Does an orthonormal basis (where one considers countably infinite sums) exist for every (possibly non-separable) Hilbert space ?

Comment: Yes, the proof is the same as in the separable case (just use transfinite induction instead of ordinary induction).

Comment: Ok, that's what you meant by bases.  I'm guessing that it still suffices to consider spanning the whole space by countable sums because of the separativity of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Well, if $B$ is an orthonormal set (possibly uncountable), the same argument as usual shows that for any vector $v$, $\|v\|^2\geq\sum_{b\in B}|\langle v,b\rangle|^2$ (where that sum is defined as the sup of finite partial sums).  Since an uncountable sum of positive numbers cannot be finite, this means that actually you must have $\langle v,b\rangle=0$ for all but countably many $b\in B$.

Comment: So, if $B$ is a maximal orthonormal set, you end up finding that $v=\sum_{b\in B}\langle v,b\rangle b$ just as always (where you can interpret that sum as the limit of the net of finite partial sums), but all but countably many of those coefficients will be $0$ automatically.

Comment: Thank you.  On your penultimate comment: did you meant it when you defined the uncountable sum by the sup of *finite* partial sums?

Comment: Yes, that's just like how a countable sum is defined as the limit (or sup, if all the terms are nonnegative) of finite partial sums.

Answer (score 4):

Every infinite-dimensional Hilbert space $H$ is the completion of some pre-Hilbert space, yes. Just take a discontinuous linear form $\alpha\colon H\longrightarrow\mathbb C$ and consider its kernel. It's a dense subspace of $H$, distinct from it.

Comment: We can consider any dense subspace, can't we?

Comment: @Berci Yes, we can.